# How to sort an JsonObject of Multiple Jsonobjects inside android

Tags: android, sorting, json

I am working on an android application and in some of my code I want to sort a JsonObject according to some value inside it in Descending order.

```
"smileys": {
      "2": {
        "image_icon": "http://devaddons1.socialengineaddons.com/mobiledemotesting/public/system/a2/39/01/1376a_0d1e.png?c=4a00",
        "id": 2,
        "count": 1
      },
      "3": {
        "image_icon": "http://devaddons1.socialengineaddons.com/mobiledemotesting/public/system/a4/39/01/1376c_35c0.png?c=59a3",
        "id": 3,
        "count": 2
      },
      "4": {
        "image_icon": "http://devaddons1.socialengineaddons.com/mobiledemotesting/public/system/a6/39/01/1376e_2019.png?c=f190",
        "id": 4,
        "count": 1
      }
    },
```

I want to sort this JsonObject based on the key value "count", so that the  JsonObject with higher count will come first and so on.
I have already tried it using the below code

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> array = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONArray smileyKeys = smileyArrays.names();
    for (int i = 0; i < smileyArrays.length(); i++) {
        try {
            array.add(smileyArrays.getJSONObject(smileyKeys.optString(i)));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(array, new Comparator<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(JSONObject lhs, JSONObject rhs) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                if(lhs.optInt("count") < rhs.getInt("count") ){
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return 0;
            }
        }
    });
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(array);
JsonObject smileysSortedAdday = jsonArray.optJSONObject(0);
```

But it is not working with JsonObject and I cannot convert it in JsonArray. Can someone please guide me how can I achieve this.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: the json you provided does not contains array...

Comment: where is smileyArrays??? can you post full code?

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar: The JsonObject I have posted above is smileyArrays which I want to sort according to the count. Please help if you know how to do it.